# Why I can't get my current user after I logged in?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, simplemembership

NET MVC 5 Simple Membership Provider. When I'm creating my user if everything is fine, I logged him in, later I want to find some info about him. But I can't get the logged in user. This is my code:

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
            var result = UserManager.Create(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {

                SignInManager.SignIn(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);
                var id = User.Identity.GetUserId();
```

So when I'm debugging and go to the `User.Identity.GetUserId();` its null. Check it out:

[image]

[image]

Comment: You already know the user Id: `user.Id`.  `User.Identity` looks at the request properties, and because they haven't been set yet, you are deemed not authenticated.  The **next** request from the client will have the correct bits populated, because the cookie will be set on the client.

Comment: @BrendanGreen Actually that helps. Do you know why is that in the next request I'm going to have the bits populated?

Answer (score 0):

Your `SignIn` method must create a cookie and store information about current logged identity. That's why you need to execute it in different request before getting information about the user. Cookie will be then created/Updated first

For my case, i start by checking if `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated()` is true, then i retrieve the Username using `User.Identity.Name`. This will return string format

Answer (score 0):

I suddenly had this problem and had to add

```
Thread.CurrentPrincipal = New GenericPrincipal(identity, {});
HttpContext.User = Thread.CurrentPrincipal;
```

Directly after my signInManager.SignIn code. No idea why it stopped working - it was fine in the morning and then was broken in the afternoon.